# `do.call` using qualified commands

Tags: r

I want to apply a qualified command utilizing `do.call`, but get
an error message.
('qualified' here means: qualified with a package name.)

```
fn = function(x) sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2])
x0 = c(pi/2, pi/2)

# qualified command works, but not with `do.call` !
numDeriv::hessian(func = fn, x = x0)
##               [,1]          [,2]
## [1,] -1.000000e+00 -5.910744e-13
## [2,] -5.910744e-13  1.063389e-15

do.call("numDeriv::hessian", list(func = fn, x = x0))
## Error in `numDeriv::hessian`(f = function (x)  : 
##   could not find function "numDeriv::hessian"

# loading the library first works too
library(numDeriv)
do.call("hessian", list(func = fn, x = x0))
##               [,1]          [,2]
## [1,] -1.000000e+00 -5.910744e-13
## [2,] -5.910744e-13  1.063389e-15
```

How can I make this work without explicitly loading the library?

EDIT: In the comments it is suggested to delete the quotes. This is true.
Unfortunately, I have to assemble the command from package and function name.
(Sorry, I didn't mention this in the original post.)

So the only way that solves my real 'challenge' is the one by Gabor:

```
fn = function(x) sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2])
x0 = c(pi/2, pi/2)

lib <- "numDeriv"
routine <- "hessian"

do.call(routine, list(func = fn, x = x0),
        envir = asNamespace(lib))
##               [,1]          [,2]
## [1,] -1.000000e+00 -5.910744e-13
## [2,] -5.910744e-13  1.063389e-15
```

Thanks Gabor, very nice. I'd give you the credits if you formulate it as an official answer.

Comment: Delete the quotes: `do.call(numDeriv::hessian, ...)`

Comment: Try `do.call("hessian", list(func = fn, x = x0), envir = asNamespace("numDeriv"))`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  Really?  Both work for me.

Comment: @user2554330  let me re-try. Ah, yes, the famous "invisible bad character" problem.  Mikael gets my apologies.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `numDeriv::hessian` is not the name of a function, it's a function call to `::` to get the function named `hessian` from the `numDeriv` package.  So you could do that yourself ahead of the call, e.g.

```
hessian <- numDeriv::hessian
do.call("hessian", list(func = fn, x = x0))
```

or (as @MikaelJagan said in a comment) pass the actual function instead of its name:

```
do.call(numDeriv::hessian, list(func = fn, x = x0))
```

These will appear slightly differently in tracebacks; my first suggestion would display as `hessian(func = ...`, while the second would display as `(function (func, x, method = "Richardson", method.args = list(),  ...) UseMethod("hessian"))(func =` .  But the results will be the same.

@G.Grothendieck gave another solution in a comment:

```
do.call("hessian", list(func = fn, x = x0), envir = asNamespace("numDeriv"))
```

This says to construct the function call, then evaluate it in the `numDeriv` namespace.  I was suspicious of it at first, because

```
hessian(func = fn, x = x0)
```

wouldn't necessarily evaluate properly in that namespace (since `fn` and `x0` aren't defined there), but that's not what it tries to evaluate.  It substitutes the values for `fn` and `x0` first, and then evaluates

```
hessian(func = function(x) sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2]), 
        x = c( 1.570796, 1.570796) )
```

This also works fine.

Comment: Lest we forget `\`numDeriv::hessian\` <- numDeriv::hessian; do.call("numDeriv::hessian", ...)` ...

Comment: No, I think we'd be better off forgetting that one!